# MS access 2010 VBA connect table with combobox and label

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I've a table that contains SUPP_CODE and SUPP_NAME columns.
I've put a combo box in my form and set the property Record Set to SUPP_NAME.

Now, I have a label in the form and I want to do the following:

```
- When user selects a SUPP_NAME in the combo box, the label will view the corresponding SUPP_CODE.
```

I did not put and ID (AutoNumber) to that table but if it is required then I can put it.

I need the tips, tricks and codes how to do this stuff.
Please help.

Comment: by the way, the form is not linked with the data table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to set up the combobox like so:

```
Row Source : Select Supp_Code, Supp_Name FROM table
Column Count : 2
Column Widths : 0cm;2cm
Bound Column : 1 ''Counting from 1
```

With this set-up, you can set a textbox to:

```
=MyCombo.Column(0) ''Supp_Code, counting from 0
```

However, because the Bound Column is 1 (Supp_Code) the value of the combo is also column 1, so you can simply say:

```
=MyCombo
```

After that, you can use domain functions such as DLookUp, DCount and DSum to get data from tables not included on a form.